# Getting onclick audio on website working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, audio, mobile, web

I'm struggling to get audio on mobile devices working and was wondering if any of you could help. I'm using mp3 as the format and it works as far as I know on desktop.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playRandomSound(){
 var sounds = [
    "http://www.website.com/media/1.mp3",
     "http://www.website.com/media/2.mp3"];

 var soundFile = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
 document.getElementById("player").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundFile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";


}
 </script>


<a href="#" onclick='playRandomSound();'>Play</a>  
                    <span id='player'></span>
```

Comment: Can you tell which part isn't working, the random function or the audio play? If I had a device for testing, I would troubleshoot by making two versions, one which plays a file without using the random, and another which does something simpler than audio, e.g., displaying the number 1 or 2 depending on the random function. Then, take it from there.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Phil! I'm pretty rubbish with javascript. I'll try and test out each part. It works in Safari, Opera, Chrome Firefox on desktop by the way but is a bit slow. This is the site (Play in the menu) http://lyambewry.co.uk/